# Problem Combining filters on EditText in KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am facing this issue with EditTexts and I am using KOTLIN.
I have added Two EditTexts to my activity and added 3 filters like so 
// Disable Space
// Max and Minimum Input
// Max Lenght
When I only have 1 filter added, it's working fine but when I add all three of them like shown on the code, only the last one is working.
My EditText 1 = Entree1
My EditText 2 = Entree2

```
        **//Min and max value**
        Entree1?.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(MinMaxFilter(1, 250))
        Entree2?.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(MinMaxFilter(1, 500))

        **//Disable space**
        Entree1?.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter { source, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            source.toString().filterNot { it.isWhitespace() }
        })
        Entree2?.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter { source, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            source.toString().filterNot { it.isWhitespace() }
        })
        **//Min and max length**
        Entree1?.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(LengthFilter(5))
        Entre2?.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(LengthFilter(4))
```

Does anybody have a more detailed explanation of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**I want to share the work around I did.
The space filter was causing the issue so I changed the filter with** `EditText.text.replace("\\s".toRegex(), "") and that did the trick`